# Why is the height of my rectangle 0?

Tags: wpf, height

The following wpf rectangle has width of 20  but a height of 0.
I would like to understand why that is.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="R" Width="20" MaxWidth="20" MinWidth="20">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="Green">
                <Rectangle Fill="Red"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: What's the height of the Border? Do you use certain styles for Rectangles?

Comment: No hidden styles. The border is as above - it fits to its content so has also height 0. In fact the `ContentPresenter` has also height 0, so the problem lies in the fact that the `DataTemplate` assumes it has no content.

Comment: you have to explicitly set the Width and Height.

Comment: @KK: well `Width` is aut. set to 20, so "do not have to". Of course setting `Height=23` works. I was wondering why W/H behave differently.

Comment: If the `Height` should be some value other than 0 or a very small one, which value do you wish it to be? automatically set to 20, 30, 40? or whatever? In fact the `HorizontalAlignment` is defaulted as `Stretch`, so it stretches the whole column's Width which is set to 20.

Comment: @KK: Indeed I would like the default stretch as in `Width`. But the `VerticalAlignment` also defaults to `Stretch`. Also the `ContentPresenters` above it all have `Stretch`. It is just that the `ContentPresenter` has `ActualHeight=0` but `ActualWidth=20`.

Comment: suppose you were the layout designer (which designed the behavior of the DataGrid in this case), what would you do in this case? automatically set some Height ***to what***? if there is some text inside the cell, the `Height` should be a bit larger the actually rendered text's Height. But in this case there is not any text. Please try imagining it, how could we determine the `Height` it should be here? The value `0` is the most suitable one, in fact there maybe some default margin which makes it a bit larger than 0.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the default cell style for `ContentAlignment` is `Stretch` for `Horizontal` and `Bottom` for `Vertical`.

From Framework 4.0 onwards it is possible to add a `CellStyle` property:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    </Style>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
```